# Display data not present in another table

Tags: mysql

`boxes : id, code`

`boxes_to_pages: template_id`

I want to display code present in code column whose id is not present in `template_id` column in boxes_to_pages table.

please help me out how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to try this

`SELECT id,code FROM boxes WHERE id NOT IN(SELECT temple_id FROM boxes_to_pages)`